# jQuery live search

Tags: jquery

I really like the [search function on iA](http://informationarchitects.jp/articles/) and I was wondering how they did it. I found ejohn.org/blog/jquery-livesearch/ by John Resig but I still don't know how to:

1. add the counter (128/128 - the number encreases and decreases)
2. highlight the word I'm searching in the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this great [auto complete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) for jquery.

By default it bolds the searching text in the results. I am sure you can change it add a css class to the search text and style it with CSS similar to IA's search.

I am sure you can also get the count of the items returned by examining the data returned.